# Slow down first layer above infill in Ultimaker Cura

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, infill

In Ultimaker Cura, is there a setting to slow down just the first layer (or two layers) covering over the infill?

I'm not talking about the top layers, since you may have infill covered over during a lower section of the print. And I'm not talking about bridging, since this isn't a true bridge, and quick testing shows the bridge settings don't seem to control this. I'm also not talking about the whole layer, since you may have just a section of a layer involved with covering the infill.

What I want, is, whenever a print transitions from infill back to shell, that first section of shell above the infill (and maybe also the next layer going the opposite direction) should be slower.

What I've observed is this layer prints at the same speed as other shell sections, which can be too fast at this point for complete coverage, leaving a stringy section. This won't be visible later, but it does matter for strength and potentially quality; if expected filament isn't deposited it has to end up somewhere. Slowing down should help get a cleaner layer.

Can Ultimaker Cura do this? I don't care which version. For completeness, what about other slicers? Even if I normally use Cura, I might be tempted to use a different slicer that can do this if I have a part where it really matters.

Comment: Yes that is probably possible, you'd need to look into the properties concerning overhang, e.g. speed. I don't have access to Ultimaker Cura now.

Comment: I don't think so. Overhanging the infill (logical solid interior) of the model is not considered overhang by Cura.

Answer (score 1):

Cura can do this. It's a bit convoluted though. Here's what you need to do:

- Load your model / scene in the build plate.
- Load an additional cube and make it as big as the entire build plate so that it overlaps with everything (in the preferences you may need to disable "Ensure that models are kept apart).
- Select the cube and go to the per-object settings tool.
- Change the cube's mesh type to "modify settings for infill".
- For the cube, set Wall Line Count to 0, Top/Bottom Thickness to 0 and Top Layers to 1. This effectively makes the cube add one additional layer on the top side of all infill volumes.
- For the cube, set the Top/Bottom Speed to your desired speed for the one slower layer.
- (Optional) In the normal settings panel on the right, set the number of top layers to be one less, so that you get the same number of top layers again.

Comment: Presumably this also works for setting other properties of the first top layer, so you could print it like a bridge?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Cura has no option to do this. Conceptually Cura treats the model as a solid, so that the material over infill is not "overhang". However, you may be able to hack it by using the "magic mesh surface mode" feature under "special modes", to treat the model as a surface rather than a solid, then enable support and use the same model as a mask for where support material should be printed, and print support as infill-only. Alternatively you might just print a second copy of the model as infill-only (0 walls and 0 layers of top/bottom skin) in the same location.